# MySQL Workbench equivalent for SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm new at SQL Server and I've been looking for an **official** database modeling tool (if there is one in existence) so that I can design EER Diagram and export it as an actual database.

So far I have only found tutorials on creating a table for a model, similar to this one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string; but since my EER contains relationships between models, I need to design the diagram.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Workbench part of writing and executing scripts .. that part .. the equivalent is Sql Server Management Studio .. Which has a free "Express" version.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx

Comment: The tutorial you give is doing the setup for POCO (object first) Entity Framework code.  EF is the ORM tool.  If you do it "code first", you can export the database after all the objects are setup.

Answer (score 1):

forget this my last information. ER Master is nice, but it isnt the answer you want.

Yes, you can do it with MS SQL Server Mangament Studio. Under the root node of datebase exists one entry "Database diagramm". If you will open this. You can choose, which Tabels you want to see in E/R Diagramm view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

http://ermaster.sourceforge.net/

its a nice plugin for eclipse.